# Giving Twitter Bootstrap Modals Dynamic IDs with PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to generate unique IDs for each modal, as I will be loading in an address specific map to each modal.  My issue is that when I click the link:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal_<? echo $meeting['ID'] ?>" ><? echo $meeting['Address'].", ".$meeting['City'] ?></a>
```

it tries to take me to mypage.php/#myModal_8 (or whatever the given ID is, instead of pulling up that specific modal.  The modals work great is I don't have the ID attached, but they won't load dynamic content that way.

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal_<? echo $meeting['ID'] ?>" ><? echo $meeting['Address'].", ".$meeting['City'] ?></a>
        </p>
        <div class="modal hide" id="#myModal_<? echo $meeting['ID'] ?>">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <? echo $meeting['Address'] ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you clarify? Are you wanting to open a model, but with different content depending on a link you've clicked?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing a stupid question but, have you included jquery library and bootstrap-modal.js/bootstrap.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the ID you are giving to the modal : `id="#myModal_<? echo $meeting['ID'] ?>"`

The `#` is only needed for the jQuery selector, not the ID. Which would give :

```
 <div class="modal hide" id="myModal_<? echo $meeting['ID'] ?>">
```

Further more, you should open your php tags with `<?php` for the reasons described here : [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/1478467)

Comment: Easy fix, thank you for the set of fresh eyes and the pointer on the short php tags.  I'm a RoR guy, so I'm just getting into the swing of PHP again.